# how can I remove this URL section from this string (representing the URL) using old JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am not so into JavaScript and I have the following problem.

I have a string like this:

```
https://smart.XXX.it/default.asp/s4
```

into a variable named **url**. Note that the last section of this url (in this case **s4** can be different).

I have to remove from this URL this section **default.asp/** and so obtain a string like:

```
https://smart.XXX.it/s4
```

How can I implement it in JavaScript?

Comment: [Replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var url = 'https://smart.XXX.it/default.asp/s4';
var var2 = url.replace('default.asp/', '');
console.log(var2);
//Output
https://smart.XXX.it/s4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `String.replace`:

```js
const url = 'https://smart.XXX.it/default.asp/s4'.replace('/default.asp', '');

console.log(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `.split()` the url like such:

```js
let url = 'https://smart.XXX.it/default.asp/s4'.split('/default.asp/').join('/');
console.log(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 'https://smart.XXX.it/default.asp/s4';
a = a.split('/');
a = a.filter((item)=>{
return item.indexOf('default.asp') === -1;
});
a = a.join('/');
```