# How can I correctly remove this URL section from a text variable representing an URL using old JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am absolutely not into JavaScript and I have the following problem. I have a string variable (named **url**) containing an URL like this:

```
var url = https://smart.XXX.it/default.asp/YYY
```

Note that the **YYY** section of this URL can be different while the **/default.asp/** section is always the same

I have to remove all this section from this URL: **/default.asp/YYY**

Basically I have to remove **/default.asp/** and all what follows this section.

How can I implement this behavior?

Comment: `url.split('/default.asp')[0]` should work but this is something that anyone with experience in any language should be able to guess.

Comment: How old is the JavaScript you are using?

Comment: or if you want something a bit more sophisticated, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Comment: P.S. this is barely any different from the question you asked half an hour ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57360346/how-can-i-remove-this-url-section-from-this-string-representing-the-url-using . Maybe you just need to do some basic Javascript study, to learn how to manipulate strings. If you can do it in Java / C# then it's not so different in JS. A trivial bit of research should not take you long. BTW what do you mean by "old" JavaScript exactly? Do you need to support some older browser or something? If so please mention exactly what you require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var url = "https://smart.XXX.it/default.asp/YYY";

console.log("original URL " + url);

console.log("updated URL " + url.split("/default.asp")[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```js
const url = "https://smart.XXX.it/default.asp/YYY";

console.log(url.replace(/default\.asp.+/, ''));
```